# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\motor-house\public_html\User.class.php on line 18

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to connect to the database from my Index file which has my login form. I have created an instance of the database, but I am getting an error.

"Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\motor-house\public_html\User.class.php on line 18"

My database class code is:

```
class Connection{

    public function Connect(){
        try{
            $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=cars', 'root', '');
            $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
            die();
        }   

        echo "rest of script";
    }

    }
```

My user class code:

```
include_once("db.class.php");

class User{
    private $db;

    //make the connection
    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new Connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->Connect();
    }

    //Login 
    public function Login($username, $password){
        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
        $query = bindParam(1, $username);
        $query = bindParam(2, $password);
        $query->execute();

        if($query->rowCount() == 1){
            echo "Granted";
        }else{
            echo "Check credentals again";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$this->db = $this->db->Connect();` looks weird.

Comment: hi matt, how do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this. My code was correct however, the only thing I was missing in the database class was the return keyword.

CODE BEFORE:
class Connection{

```
public function Connect(){
    try{
        $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=cars', 'root', '');
        $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }   

    echo "rest of script";
}


}
```

Code after:

class Connection{

```
public function Connect(){
    try{
        return $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=cars', 'root', '');
        $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }   

    echo "rest of script";
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mat is correct. You are instantiating a new object and assigning it to the property `$db` on this line:

```
    $this->db = new Connection();
```

But then you are overriding that assignment in the next line:

```
    $this->db = $this->db->Connect();
```

So you no longer have an instantiated object containing the method `prepare()`.

Change that to:

```
//make the connection
public function __construct(){
    $this->db = new Connection();
    $this->db->Connect();
}
```

Comment: Hi Wolf, thanks for the correction. When I change the code, I now get a error like this: "Fatal error: Call to undefined method Connection::prepare() in C:\wamp\www\motor-house\public_html\User.class.php on line 18"

Comment: @user3179918 Do you have a `prepare()` method in your `Connection` class?

Comment: no only in the user class

public function Login($username, $password){
  $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
  $query = bindParam(1, $username);
  $query = bindParam(2, $password);
  $query->execute();

Comment: also, dosen't PDO have an inbuilt prepare statement?

Comment: Your code is saying, "call the prepare method in the Connection object." If you want to use the PDO `prepare()`, then you need to make the PDO instance available to reference outside of the Connection class. Try declaring `public $handler` and then assigning the PDO instance to `$this->handler`. Then call `$this->handler->prepare()` in `User`.

Comment: Hi Wolf, would you be able to show me an example please. I am still new to PDO and oop php. Thanks